# How to remove the angular scope array values using key name?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an angular scope array now i want to remove one item from that array using key name for example i want to remove DataTypeName from that array.

```
$scope.attributes = [
 {DataTypeName: "Text"
objectAttributeDataTypeId: "3654B05F-E09E-49A9-8E5F-0FC623BBE009"
objectAttributeId: "9df52354-67dd-453a-87fd-abb38b448db9"
objectAttributeLabelName: "test"
objectAttributeName: "test"}]
```

Please anyone help me to remove the array.

Comment: you want to remove DataTypeName property from all the item in the array.. Is my understanding is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you need to remove the `objectAttributeDataTypeId` from the first element of the array which is a object.

so what you need is,

```
$scope.attributes[0] // get the first element of the array
$scope.attributes[0].DataTypeName // get the DataTypeName attribute of the object
delete $scope.attributes[0].DataTypeName; // delete the property.
```

so all you need is,

```
delete $scope.attributes[0].DataTypeName;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter array you can use native [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method for this:

```js
$scope = {}; // stub $scope for demo
$scope.attributes = [
  {
    DataTypeName: "Text",
    objectAttributeDataTypeId: "3654B05F-E09E-49A9-8E5F-0FC623BBE009",
    objectAttributeId: "9df52354-67dd-453a-87fd-abb38b448db9",
    objectAttributeLabelName: "test",
    objectAttributeName: "test"
  },
  {
    DataTypeName: "Image",
    objectAttributeDataTypeId: "3654B05F-E09E-49A9-8E5F-0FC623BBE009",
    objectAttributeId: "9df52354-67dd-453a-87fd-abb38b448db9",
    objectAttributeLabelName: "test",
    objectAttributeName: "test"
  }
];

// Filter out only "Text" types
$scope.filtered = $scope.attributes.filter(function(attr) {
    return attr.DataTypeName == "Text";
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify($scope.filtered, null, 4));
```